# How can I get a list of arguments _expected_ by a function?

Tags: php

I need to be able to interrogate a function/method and get a list of the arguments which that function *expects*, from *outside* the function, *before* the function is called.

So not argument values, but a list of expected argument 'slots' per say.

Possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at PHP Reflection - specifically the ReflectionParameter class...

http://nz.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.reflection.php#language.oop5.reflection.reflectionparameter